# Showing the Heisenberg Group is Isomorphic to the set $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, group-isomorphism

The 1-dimensional Heisenberg group $\mathbb{H}^1$ with group operation
$$(s,x,y)\cdot(s',x',y') = (s+s' + \frac{1}{2}(xy' - x'y), x+x', y+y')$$
is supposedly isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$ with group law given by
$$(s,x,y)\star(s',x',y') = (s+s' + xy', x+x', y+y')$$
by using the map (call it $f$) $(s,x,y) \mapsto (s+\frac{1}{2}xy, x,y)$. How exactly do we show this with computation? I get extra terms that shouldn't be there when I try myself.

So checking the relation $f((s,x,y)\cdot (s',x',y')) = f((s,x,y))\star f((s',x',y'))$, beginning with the LHS:

$$f((s,x,y)\cdot (s',x',y')) = f((s+s' +\frac{1}{2}(xy' - x'y),x+x',y+y')) = (s+s' +\frac{1}{2}(xy' - x'y) + \frac{1}{2}(x+x')(y+y'),x+x',y+y') = (s+s' + \frac{1}{2}(2xy' + xy  + x'y'), x+x',y+y') $$.

Looking at the RHS now:

$$f((s,x,y))\star f((s',x',y')) = (s+\frac{1}{2}xy,x,y)\star (s'+\frac{1}{2}x'y', x',y') = (s+s'+\frac{1}{2}xy+ \frac{1}{2}x'y' + \frac{1}{2}xy',x)$$

As you can see I am off by a factor of a $\frac{1}{2} xy'$.

Comment: Perhaps you could show us your work. By the way, it would help to use different symbols for the two group operations as well as the map you gave. So you want something like $m(g \star _1g')=m(g) \star_2m(g').$

Comment: No problem, I'll add an edit now (changing the sign for the second group operation). I'll also work on typing up some workings.

Comment: Your problem is at the last step. You have some typos and wrong $xy'$ and forgot the $x+x',y+y')$ part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $f:(s,x,y)\mapsto(s+c_1xy/2,x,y)$ is a mapping between the two group laws:
$$(s,x,y)\cdot(s',x',y') = (s+s' + \frac12(c_2xy' +c_3 x'y), x+x', y+y') $$
and
$$(s,x,y)\star(s',x',y') = (s+s'+\frac12((c_1+c_2)xy'+(c_1+c_3)x'y),x+x',y+y')$$
which are both associative. Then verify the equation
$$f((s,x,y)\cdot(s',x',y'))=f(s,x,y)\star f(s',x',y').$$
In your case, you want to specialize to $\;c_1=c_2=1,c_3=-1.$